# XPath: How do I select text() or a span element within a parent element

Tags: xpath

I have a parent element (font) and I would like to select all the child elements (direct descendants) that are either text() or span elements.  How would I construct such an xpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the current node is the `font` element, then something like this:

```
text()|span
```

otherwise you have to always combine with `|` the two complete XPath - the one for text and the one for span, e.g.:

```
font/text()|font/span
```

if the current node is just above `font` - or

```
//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/span|//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/text()
```

if starting from the root with some complex selection criteria.

If you have complex paths like the last one probably it is better to store a partial one in a variable - e.g. inside an XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="font" select="//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font"/>

. . . 

<xsl:for-each select="$font/span|$font/text()">
  . . . 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Another possibility is to do something like this:

```
//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/node()[name()='span' or name()='']
```

that works because `name()` returns an empty string for `text()` nodes - but I am not 100% sure that it works that way for all XPath processors, and it could match by mistake comment nodes.

Comment: Do I need some parens or something similar because if I try "//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/span|text()", I get the child span (but no text elements) and if I do "//a[text()='View Larger Map']/../../../../div[contains(@class, 'paragraph')][3]/font/text()|span", I get the text elements but no span.  Thanks for any clarifications

Comment: Comment nodes also don't have a name. Therefore, this answer needs to be corrected. The document node (root node) is another type of node that has no name, but it is safe to be ommitted from consideration in this specific case.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I wrote '...and it could match by mistake comment nodes' - the second solution can be used only if you are sure that there are no commentsw in the source, the first one should work always.

Comment: @MiMo: Yes. What I said in my comment is that it isn't acceptable to provide a solution that is problematic and point out its problems. Much better is to fix this problematic solution and provide the fixed solution -- and this *is* possible in this particular case.